# What happens when multiple users save an "unshared" workbook on a shared drive?

Tags: windows, vba, excel

If several people run a VBA macro that uses Workbooks.Open() which opens the same workbook on a shared network drive, makes changes to it, and then saves it, what behavior should I expect? Assume all 5 macros attempt to make the save at the same time?

The Workbook being edited in this manner is not a "shared workbook".

The desired behavior would be that the last save to process would stick, overwriting any conflicting changes the previously processed saves produced.

Are there any errors I'd have to worry about? Would Window's filesystem have any problems with this? Could this potentially cause a application or OS crash?

**Background:**
I'm working on a project where 4-5 people in a company want to make simultaneous updates to a workbook. They've had a lot of problems using excel's "shared workbook" setup; specifically, they don't want to bother with the way it handles with conflict resolution. The fastest solution I can come up with is having them use separate workbooks that synchronize with a master workbook on one of their shared drives. I'm going to set it up so synchronization will only add records or modify columns in existing records to the master workbook. Modifications will be handled by using a natural key made up of three columns in their workbook to identify corresponding records in the local and master workbook, so I don't have to worry about whether or not those records are on the same numbered row.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be much better to use a backend database such as Jet which has transaction logging built-in.

Comment: I may go that route, but I wanted to explore all my options, and I'm curious how excel/windows would handle this use-case.

Comment: Opening a non-shared workbook (whether by VBA or manually) will lock the workbook to that user. As @CharlesWilliams pointed out, you really need a backend database to collect data in a way that can be "shared" without conflicts. If desired, the data can be pushed/pulled to Excel later.

Comment: If the workbook is locked to that user, will the other user's Workbooks.Open() requests block until that lock is released?

Comment: When its locked then other users can only open a read-only copy. This is not going to even begin to work in your scenario. For your scenario you should use Excel as the frontend to a backend shared database.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesWilliams If you put this in an answer I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first user to open it locks it then other users can only open a read-only copy. This is not going to even begin to work in your scenario.
 For your scenario you should use Excel as the frontend to a backend shared database